# How to carry calculation and draw plot lines in a web page?

Tags: html, graphs, calculator

I have a website that I code in html (from Wordpress, specifically, but it could be any). I would like to create a page in which

- the user inputs a small number of parameters and makes a few yes/not choice with buttons.
- based on those parameters and choices, his/her computer should create two arrays of numbers based on operations that are hard-coded. These operations are basic arithmetic, but they could also entail some simple trigonometry (sinus, cosinus) and a random numbers. I reckon to compute 100/200 numbers per array.
- Finally, the computer plots the two arrays of numbers in a plain graph with titles, labels, ticks and so forth.

Which software, programming language or package thereof is able to realize this?

Comment: You could achieve this client-side with JavaScript or server-side with any means of server-side scripting (e.g., CGI, FastCGI, your favorite web framework).

Answer (score 1):

## Vaadin

The [Vaadin Framework](https://vaadin.com/framework) is an open-source free-of-cost project to build desktop-style business-oriented web apps in pure Java. Your app runs on the server-side in Java but is automatically rendered for the user in a Wen browser using HTML5 web standards. The great advantage is that, while used under the covers by Vaadin, there is no need for you to learn HTML, CSS, DOM, JavaScript, WebSocket, Push, and such. All you need to learn is Java.

[Vaadin Charts](https://vaadin.com/charts) is a commercial add-on for drawing interactive charts.

Search this site for other informative Answers about Vaadin.

Java offers the [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class with some trig functions. And I'd bet you could find other libraries in Java if you have special needs.